# Type of Deserialize Object

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

I have command as below:

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText("C:\\...\\file.json");
var jsonStringConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(jsonString);
```

In `file.json` I have data of type `MyClass`. Could you tell me what is `IEnumerable<MyClass>` ? How can I get any element from jsonStringConvert?   Of course, `IEnumerable` is an interface.

Comment: Could you post a partial set of the contents of `file.json`?

Comment: You cannot deserialize to `IEnumerable<T>` because the deserializer needs to create an instance of *something* to deserialize into. `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface, so it cannot be instantiated. Also, where is the code for `MyClass`? Where's the input JSON?

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable` is a collection of `MyClass` instances.  Or rather, could become a collection of `MyClass` instances assuming the deserialization happens correctly.  But, like @jon pointed out, you've really got to instantiate one or more `MyClass` objects and fill up the collection.